# How can I get my first-person character in Unity to move to a ledge with an animation?

Tags: animation, unity, javascript

I'm trying to get this to happen:
The character walks up to a large crate, the player presses a button, and an animation starts playing where the character climbs up on to the crate. (all in first person view).

So far I tried this with normal "First Person Controller" Prefab in Unity.

My code so far:

```
function OnTriggerStay(other : Collider){
    if(other.tag == "GrabZone"){
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("e")){
            animation.Play("JumpToLedge");
        }
    }
}
```

However when i use this on The FPC it will always play from the position the animation is created on.

I also tried to create an empty game object, placing the FPC in there. Gives same effect.

I also tried just animating the graphics of the FPC alone. This seems to work but since the Character Controller itself is not animated that stays onthe ground. So the whole FPC wont work anymore.

Is there anyway i could let this animation play on the local position the player is on at that time?

Or can you think of any other logical solution for a grab and climb?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of an odd usage, but you could set the [blendMode](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/AnimationState-blendMode.html) to Additive and make sure your animation starts at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

This might be able to help you, I haven't used it, but it is supposed to help you with dynamically blending animations to match your level.

http://unity3d.com/support/resources/unity-extensions/locomotion-ik.html

Good luck :)